# Oracle Joins with multiple values to one value

Tags: sql, oracle

I am trying to join between the two tables On one column with one value and other column with multiple values.

```
For ex. table1 column varieties     table2 Items
        Fruits                      vegetables,spinach,fruits
        Vegetable 
        Spinach
```

Is there any way I can join like this:

```
select * from table1 t1 left join table2 t2  on t1.varieties in t2.items
```

Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 3):

It sounds like you have a comma delimited list in the column `t1.items`.  This is bad database design.  The right design is to have a separate association table.

However, you can do the join using `like`:

```
select *
from table1 t1 left join
     table2 t2
     on ','||t1.items||',' like '%,'||t2.varieties||',%'
```

Note that this puts a delimited at the beginning and end of the list and then searches for words surrounded by the delimited.  This prevents "apple" from matching "pineapple".

Comment: Hi Gordon,

Thanks for your reply. I have tried that method but it's not working :(

Comment: @James . . . You have since clarified your question.  I had the comma delimited list on the wrong variable.  Try it again.